# Parsing sections and getting lines in between

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have csv file in the following format

```
Section "Test A",
1,F-1,A-2,D-5,
2,A-1,D-2,E-5,
Section "Test B",
3,C-2,D-1,F-5,
4,D-1,B-2,C-1,
5,E-1,B-3,C-4,
Section "Test C",
6,A-2,D-1,C-4,
```

I am trying to get the following output

```
Test A
1,F-1,A-2,D-5,
2,A-1,D-2,E-5,

Test B
3,C-2,D-1,F-5,
4,D-1,B-2,C-1,
5,E-1,B-3,C-4,

Test C
6,A-2,D-1,C-4,
```

I am able to just parse through it, but can't figure out how to get the lines for the specific section.

Code i am working with

```
import csv

with open('list.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    lreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in lreader:
        test = (', '.join(row))
        if "Section" in test:
            print(test)
```

Comment: yes just posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
t = open('your_file.csv').readlines()

for i in range(len(t)):
    if 'Section' in t[i]:
        t[i]=t[i].replace('Section ', '').replace('"', '').replace(',', '')

with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(t)
```

Output:

```
Test A
1,F-1,A-2,D-5,
2,A-1,D-2,E-5,
Test B
3,C-2,D-1,F-5,
4,D-1,B-2,C-1,
5,E-1,B-3,C-4,
Test C
6,A-2,D-1,C-4,
```